# How to get element from array inside Arraylist<String[]>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```java
ArrayList<String[]> hold3 = new ArrayList<>();
String [] str1 = {"a","b","c"};
String [] str4 = {"d","e","f"};
String [] str3 = {"g","h","i"};

hold3.add(str1);
hold3.add(str4);
hold3.add(str3);
hold3.get(1);
```

In this type of data structure, I can get elements of ArrayList with help of the `.get()` method. Is there any way to return some element of a string array? (e.g when I say `.get(1)` it returns `[d,e,f]`, but I want to return `[d]`)

Comment: hold3.get(1)[0] for getting array's first element hold3.get(1)[1] for getting array's second element etc

Comment: Your `ArrayList` holds arrays of `String`, not `String` itself.

Answer (score 4):

You just could *unfold* (or reverse) how the values were saved into the list:

---

Note: "ArrayList takes String as an object" is not correct in this case, it takes an array of Strings (`String[]`)!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The `.get(1)` returns a `String[]`, so you use the same syntax you use to access elements of any `String[]`. It's `[]`. Like,

```
System.out.println(hold3.get(1)[0]);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
d
```

Answer (score 3):

When you retrieve the array, use the index of the array to get the String.

```
 ArrayList<String[]> hold3 = new ArrayList<>();
 String [] str1 = {"a","b","c"};
 String [] str4 = {"d","e","f"};
 String [] str3 = {"g","h","i"};

String s = hold3.get(1)[1];  // gets 'e'
```